# F# Make - Restore certain Nuget packages with PreRelease option

Tags: f#-fake

In order to specify additional internal company Nuget feeds, I am currently using `RestorePackages` like this:

```
let RestorePackages() =
    !! "./**/packages.config"
    |> Seq.iter (RestorePackage(fun p -> {p with Sources = "http://internal.example.com/nuget" :: p.Sources}))
```

Which works great. How can I get the script to restore certain packages with the `IncludePreRelease` option set?

I have tried matching on the package like this:

```
let RestorePackages() =
    !! "./**/packages.config"
    |> Seq.iter (fun item ->
        match item with
        | "Example" -> RestorePackageId(fun p -> {p with IncludePreRelease = true}) "Example"
        | item -> RestorePackage(fun p -> {p with Sources = "http://internal.example.com/nuget" :: p.Sources}))
```

But that doesn't work. The default match to call `RestorePackage` says "This expression was expected to have type unit but here has type string -> unit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a string at the end of your last code line. I think you should pass `item` variable there.

```
    let RestorePackages() =
        !! "./**/packages.config"
        |> Seq.iter (fun item ->
            match item with
            | "Example" -> RestorePackageId(fun p -> {p with IncludePreRelease = true}) "Example"
            | item -> RestorePackage(fun p -> {p with Sources = "http://internal.example.com/nuget" :: p.Sources}) item)
```